# Post to twitter via curl

Tags: php, curl

I have to allow a customer to publish articles on the blog that I'm building and automatically publish the post on twitter, facebook and linkedin.
I can not create an application facebook / twitter to customers and even give me the password.
So I would like to create a post from php using curl (or other method).
I found this:
http://www.flameweb.net/using_php_to_update_twitter
I entered my username and password, run the code and it returns "success" but there are no posts on twitter.
why?

Answer (score 2):

This is a modified version of [a script](https://github.com/lukapusic/twitter-bot/blob/master/tweet.sh) from [360percents.com](http://360percents.com). It uses mobile twitter. It worked when i used it, I didnt check now.

Signin.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

#REQUIRED PARAMS
username=$1
password=$2
cookie="$username.cookie"

#EXTRA OPTIONS
uagent="Mozilla/5.0"
#proxy="--socks5 127.0.0.1:9050"

#INITIAL PAGE
initpage=`curl $proxy -s -b $cookie -c $cookie -L --sslv3 -A "$uagent" "https://mobile.twitter.com/session/new"`
token=`echo "$initpage" | grep "authenticity_token" | sed -e 's/.*value="//' | sed -e 's/" \/>.*//' | tail -n 1`

#LOGIN
loginpage=`curl $proxy -s -b $cookie -c $cookie -L --sslv3 -A "$uagent" -d "authenticity_token=$token&username=$username&password=$password" "https://mobile.twitter.com/session"`
```

Tweet.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

#REQUIRED PARAMS
username=$1
password="$2"
tweet=$3
cookie="$username.cookie"

#EXTRA OPTIONS
uagent="Mozilla/5.0"
#proxy="--socks5 127.0.0.1:9050"

#HOME PAGE
homepage=`curl $proxy -s -b $cookie -c $cookie -L -A "$uagent" "http://mobile.twitter.com/"`
if [ "$homepage" != "${homepage/Sign in/}" ]; then
    echo "Signing $username in"
    ./signin.sh $username $password
fi

echo "Tweeting $tweet by $username"

#TWEET
tweettoken=`echo "$homepage" | grep "authenticity_token" | sed -e 's/.*value="//' | sed -e 's/" \/>.*//' | tail -n 1`
update=`curl $proxy -s -b $cookie -c $cookie -L -A "$uagent" -d "authenticity_token=$tweettoken&tweet[text]=$tweet&tweet[display_coordinates]=false" "http://mobile.twitter.com/"`
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the Twitter API?

[REST API v1.1](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1)